# NTP client of poco library not working as expected

Tags: c++, synchronization, poco-libraries, ntp

I trying to implement an NTP client so as to compute offset and delay on a cubietruck board (ARM® Cortex™-A7 Dual-Core) with armbian (Debian 9.6 stretch) os. I used the Poco Library (version 1.7.8p2) and code similar to the example that poco provides. The following is the main.cpp:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include  "NTPClientTest.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace NTP;


void NtpServerSynchronization::ntpTimeSync()
{


    _ntpClient.request("pool.ntp.org");

}


void NtpServerSynchronization::onResponse(const void* pSender, NTPEventArgs& args)
{


    auto t1 = args.packet().originateTime().epochMicroseconds();
    auto t2 = args.packet().receiveTime().epochMicroseconds();
    auto t3 = args.packet().transmitTime().epochMicroseconds();
}



int main()
{
    try {


        NtpServerSynchronization ntp;
        ntp.ntpTimeSync();  

    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

While the header NTPClientTest consists of the following:

```
#include <Poco/Net/NTPClient.h>
#include <Poco/Net/NTPEventArgs.h>
#include <Poco/Delegate.h>


using namespace Poco;
using namespace Poco::Net;
using namespace std;


namespace NTP {

    class NtpServerSynchronization
        /// Class for time synchronization with ntp server
    {
    public:


        NtpServerSynchronization() :
            _ntpClient(IPAddress::IPv4)
        {
            _ntpClient.response += Delegate<NtpServerSynchronization, NTPEventArgs>(this, &NtpServerSynchronization::onResponse);
        }

        ~NtpServerSynchronization()
        {
            _ntpClient.response -= Delegate<NtpServerSynchronization, NTPEventArgs>(this, &NtpServerSynchronization::onResponse);
        }

        void ntpTimeSync();


        void onResponse(const void* pSender, NTPEventArgs& args);



    private:

        NTPClient _ntpClient;
        SocketAddress _sa;
    };
}
```

However the values I get are:

```
t1 = 2085978496000000
t2 = 1549296374000000
t3 = 1549296374000000
```

As on can see t1 does not correspond to valid epoch timestamp and t2==t3 meaning that  receiveTime and transmitTime are the same and I got the similar result whichever ntp server I used.
What am I doing wrong regarding t1 and is the equality of the t2, t3 logical?